# How do I clean up my dconf database?

Tags: dconf, maintenance

Dconf is pretty young, yet my database is already a mess with lots of "schema-less" keys. Is there a way to do some cleaning up, or would I need to start from scratch (by removing ~/.config/dconf/user I guess)?

Comment: any chance you can add a screen-shot of what you are seeing?  I dont see the same issue.

Comment: Use any software that makes use of GSettings/dconf, change one of the default values (eg. gnome-nettool, run a whois), remove the application. You now have the remains in your database (eg. in apps.gnome-nettool). Good if you reinstall that software at a later point, yet I want to remove those keys.

Comment: A quick online search let me find a [Google Code project](http://code.google.com/p/gconf-cleaner/) that seems to do something similar for gconf...could this be modified to work with dconf?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the text file and attempting a find a replace operaation to remove all the unwanted items from your dconf?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is possible using the `dconf reset` command, though it's not clear if that's a side-effect of a bug.

- For a single key:

  ```
  dconf reset "/path/to/the/key"
  ```

  **Must not** end with a `/`.
- For a whole path:

  ```
  dconf reset -f "/path/to/the/path/"
  ```

  **Must** end with a `/`.

If you do this while having `dconf-editor` opened, it will likely crash.

Comment: I think a warning is warranted: you may be tempted to do a `dconf reset -f /`, but besides clearing out schema-less keys, **`reset` resets _all_ affected values to their defaults**. In any case, I recommend backing up your existing configuration (with `dconf dump / >my-dconf.dump`) before issuing a `dconf reset`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to clean the dconf database, you first have to dump the whole dconf configuration via:

```
morfik:~$ cd ~/.config/dconf/
morfik:~/.config/dconf$ dconf dump / > user-backup
morfik:~/.config/dconf$ ls -al ./user-backup
-rw-r--r-- 1 morfik morfik 30.0K 2015-02-07 08:18:04 ./user-backup
morfik:~/.config/dconf$ rm user
```

After those steps you have to reopen your graphical session (log out/in). This will create the `~/.config/dconf/user` file anew with almost 0 content -- default settings.

As for the `user-backup` file you had created earlier, it's just a plain text file:

```
...
[apps/light-locker]
late-locking=false
lock-after-screensaver=uint32 1
lock-on-suspend=true
...
```

So you can edit it and remove the desired entries/blocks from that file. In other words -- clean it.

When you're done, load it:

```
morfik:~/.config/dconf$ dconf load / < ./user-backup
morfik:~/.config/dconf$ ls -al ./user-backup
-rw-r--r-- 1 morfik morfik 14.0K 2015-02-07 08:26:23 ./user-backup
morfik:~/.config/dconf$ dconf update /
```

I think you should restart your graphical session after that again.

And that's it, but you have to remember that all entries that have default values wont be saved -- they will be created anew when some app will ask for it, which is a good thing because you want to backup only the values you had changed.

Comment: This actually does not seem to have any effect whatsoever on the dconf subpath being dumped modified and reloaded. (I work with an fully updated Ubuntu 14.04.2 and try to remove all keys that have to do with the package indicator-netspeed-unity from ppa:fixnix/netspeed.)  It looks like a clean way to go about it but just does NOT effect any change.

Comment: I redid this to be sure, but I confirm this does not effect any change whatsoever.  I guess I voted that answer up a little too fast. Can't undo that now.

Comment: I updated the answer, check it -- it works for me.

Comment: Yes, it now works well. Removing ~/.config/dconf/user before ending your unity session and starting anew were the missing steps. The up-vote stands. Thank you.

Comment: This saved me when I got a black screen after logging in to gnome. After opening a tty with `Alt+Ctrl+F3`, I was able to perform these steps. An additional useful command was `sudo pkill -u <username>` to restart the active gnome desktop session.

Comment: In ubuntu-18 works also. I removed `~/.config/dconf/user`. On logout-login it was auto-restoring the file again as it was (from some cache I guess) so  I had do the following:  **1.** Switch to term with `Ctl-Alt-1`    **2**. remove the file **3.** provide `reboot` comand on the term. After reboot a: `dconf load / < ./user-backup` works instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Install `gconf-cleaner` from the software center.
`sudo apt-get install gconf-cleaner`

In their own words "GConf Cleaner is a tool to clean your Gconf database up that is possibly cluttered with unnecessary or invalid keys."

Comment: Does not anymore exist in software centre as of Ubuntu 18.04 (and possibly earlier)

Comment: Gconf is deprecated and not the same than dconf.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to this, but I found a way to remove particularly stubborn old entries that isn't mentioned here. In `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas`, there will be several `.gschema.xml` files. Look there, you'll probably find files associated with those entries.

Remove them like this.

```
rm -v /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.shell.extensions.stubborn.gschema.xml
```

Then recompile the `gschemas.compiled` file with this command:

```
glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

From there, I used Alt+F2 > r to reload. Not sure if that's necessary. If using Wayland, you'll probably have to restart if it is. And the entries were gone.