# Remove useless entries in dconf schema tree

Tags: 15.04, gnome-terminal, ubuntu-gnome, dconf

I'm using GNOME 3.16

I have the following entries in my dconf-database. The entries are `gnome-terminal` profiles.

```
% dconf dump / | grep legacy 
[org/gnome/terminal/legacy] 
[org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:] 
[org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:4d4a684a-7388-40db-adf1-6ec6b6f9043d] 
[org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:f36134ca-ebb6-4824-8403-6c11c8a135e8]
```

The same schema in the `dconf-editor`.

[image]

The entry `:f36134ca-…` *was* a terminal profile, but the profile does not exist anymore in the profile list in `gnome-terminal` . How can I remove the useless entry/profile?

Comment: I think [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/85755/295286) already has a solution. In my current install of 14.04 I don't have dconf entry for gnome-terminal but I tested it with one gedit schema and it was gone, so . . . i guess that's most likely what you are looking for

Comment: @Serg I think, it's a 15.04 problem.

Comment: what exactly  is the problem?

Comment: @Serg Remove the entry `:f36134ca-ebb6-4824-8403-6c11c8a135e8`

Comment: I'm sorry for Ravan, who just started a bounty, but have you tried this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/45535/how-do-i-clean-up-my-dconf-database

Comment: @kos I'm using GNOME 3.16 and the described schema is new in this version. Therefore no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the entry `f36134ca-ebb6-4824-8403-6c11c8a135e8` from the output of

```
dconf dump / | grep legacy
```

and add it again to the values of the key with the name `list`.

Now open `gnome-terminal` and remove the profile.

Comment: Since he is on GNOME 3.16 can it be that dconf-editor does not recognize some keys from the upstream 3.16 release?  dconf-editor version 0.22.01, my terminal profile has many more values listed on the right.

Comment: @xtrchessreal my understanding is that newer  gnome-terminal just reads different schemas than before and has nothing to do with dconf itself