# Ubuntu 18.04 Places menu failure

Tags: 18.04, places, gnome-flashback

Running Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME flashback.

1. Top panel shows (from left) "Applications  Places…".
2. Click on "Places" displays a drop-down menu starting "Home", "Desktop", "Documents", etc.

   [image: places menu]
3. Clicking on any item e. g. "Documents" opens a box on the lower
   panel labelled "Opening Documents", which disappears after about ten seconds.

   [image: background window in panel]

   No other result, no error message, no dialog.

From a terminal entering "nautilus Desktop" succeeds correctly.
Any help would be gratefully accepted.

~$ dir  .local/share/applications
total 100K
drwx------  2 mike mike 4.0K Sep 26 10:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 32 mike mike 4.0K Sep 26 10:07 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 mike mike  172 Sep 19 12:55 alacarte-made-1.desktop
-rw-r--r--  1 mike mike  148 Sep 26 10:06 alacarte-made-2.desktop
-rw-r--r--  1 mike mike  133 Sep 15 07:36 alacarte-made.desktop
-rw-r--r--  1 mike mike  348 Sep 11 07:31  com.canonical.launcher.amazon.desktop
-rw-r--r--  1 mike mike  333 Sep 11 07:32 gksu.desktop
-rw-r--r--  1 mike mike  329 Sep 17 17:29 mount-archive.desktop
-rw-r--r--  1 mike mike  488 Sep 26 10:03 nautilus-folder-handler.desktop
-rw-r--r--  1 mike mike  534 Sep 17 17:33 org.gnome.Cheese.desktop
-rw-r--r--  1 mike mike 1.2K Sep 18 10:16 org.gnome.Logs.desktop
-rw-r--r--  1 mike mike 2.7K Sep 19 11:45 org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
-rw-r--r--  1 mike mike  22K Sep 17 17:33 org.gnome.Totem.desktop
-rw-r--r--  1 mike mike  634 Sep 17 17:33 rhythmbox-device.desktop
-rw-r--r--  1 mike mike  20K Sep 17 17:33 totem.desktop
-rw-r--r--  1 mike mike  333 Sep 11 07:31 ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop

Comment: I don't see how this helps, but here goes: https://alpha.mike-r.com/~mike/fullscreen-1.png and https://alpha.mike-r.com/~mike/fullscreen2.png

Comment: Thanks. I have a much better idea of the situation now. Can you please try to replicate the issue with a pristine (temporary) user account (e. g. an ephemeral guest session)?

Comment: Created a new user ("dummy"; "Guest" does not work any more) Logged in using the same DM - problem vanished.  So its something local to my account, but I cant think what it could be

Comment: Let’s try to narrow it down to a particular configuration source. Can you 1) [back-up the Dconf database](/a/522843/175814), 2) [reset it](/a/85755/175814), 3) log out and back in and 4) try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Followed instructions in  https://askubuntu.com/questions/45535/how-do-i-clean-up-my-dconf-database/85755#85755; logged out and back in -- problem persists.   Restored dconf ; still no cigar.  I guess i'll just get used to ignoring the 'Places' menu.

Comment: I forgot to specify that you should reset the entire database with `dconf reset -f /`. I hope you understood and did that anyway. :-) In that case let’s take a look at the `~/.config` directory: is there anything that looks like it might pertain to the configuration of GNOME, GNOME Fallback, the GNOME panel, or Mutter (GNOME’s window manager/compositor)? What if you delete/rename those? You can also take a shot at the paths mentioned in https://askubuntu.com/a/56314/175814.

Comment: Can you show what files you have in .local/share/applications? Also have you tried to look in logs? Is there something related to gnome-panel and/or nautilus?