# dconf remove obsolete panel object

Tags: dconf

I have a persistent obsolete object on the panel. The application was removed several updates ago and I see errors `chromium.desktop not found`.

I have installed the dconf-editor through which I can see the offending item but I do not see an option to delete it.

I have dconf dumped to a file, removed the offending object from the dump file and then reloaded the edited file. This doesn't remove the object because suppose this is because the dconf database is not over-written by the load but modified in place.

The entry in the dump looks like this :

```
[org/mate/panel/objects/object-21]
launcher-location='chromium-browser.desktop'
object-type='launcher'
panel-right-stick=false
position=320
toplevel-id='top'
```

It is referenced in the panel definition as one of the objects in this way

```
object-id-list=['notification-area', 'clock', 'object-0',... 'object-21',...'object-24']
```

I have tried `dconf reset /org/mate/panel/objects/object-21` but it persists

I am missing a step. I could completely clear the dconf database and reload it from the dump

```
 dconf load / < dconf.edited
```

But I don't see how to clear the database.

Is there another way to remove this object -- or a way to clear the database?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clean up my dconf database?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45535/how-do-i-clean-up-my-dconf-database)

Comment: Guessing wildly here but could it have something to do with chromium being a snap package in 19.10? Maybe some residual files persist? A couple of years ago, there were issues of snap-related files persisting. What does `locate chromium-browser.desktop` show?

Comment: @ajgringo619 Yes Mikhail's solution works to clean the database. Delete the user file and restart the user session. Then reload the dump file.

Comment: @JusticeforMonica It wasn't only chromium that was persisting. It was with two other applications as well, one of which I had built and installed myself. The problem is in the caching of the dconf database and that it's sticky. I needed to clear the user session through a restart.