# Missing Ubuntu Dock

Tags: ubuntu-dock, dock

I installed Dash to Dock Extension on Ubuntu 20.10
But gradually my computer slowed down
So I removed Dash to Dock and now Ubuntu Dock is Disappearing

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on the **Ubuntu Dock** extension using either "Gnome Tweaks" (`gnome-tweak-tool` or `gnome-tweaks`) or, on more recent versions of Ubuntu, "Extensions" (`gnome-shell-extension-prefs`). None of these utilities are installed by default on Ubuntu.

It is advised to **reset** the settings of the dock to the **factory defaults**. "Ubuntu Dock" uses the same settings as "Dash to Dock", so any configuration you did to the latter will carry on to the default dock. You can [reset all dconf settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45535/how-do-i-clean-up-my-dconf-database#85755) for Dash to dock with the command

```
dconf reset -f "/org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/"
```

You may need to log out and then back in to see things restored.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Comment: @Robert, thanks for the benefit of other users of the site to give feedback on the answer. It it helped you, then show thanks and hint future readers by "accepting" the anser, i.e. checking the checkmark.