# Missing Dock in Ubuntu 20.04 after sudo apt upgrade and restart

Tags: apt, upgrade, multiple-monitors, ubuntu-dock

I did `sudo apt upgrade` and restarted Ubuntu 20.04 system. However, after login the Dock is missing from the desktop environment. The Dock does appear on the left edge of the monitor when I press the `Super` button to enter the `Activities` screen.

I have tried solutions [1](https://askubuntu.com/a/1318582/541417) and also doing

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
```

Each time reboot to check the appearance of the dock. Still missing.

noticed something strange in `Settings` --> `Appearance` --> `Dock`.  `Icon size` is 0 and can't be changed and `Show on` is blank. `Position on screen` was initially blank. I could selected any of the options but Dock still does not appear. See image

[image: Settings-Appearance-Dock Issue]

Quite sometime ago, I had installed `Dash-to-Dock` and uninstalled it. Dock still appears and worked well for weeks until this upgrade. According to apt log, the affected  packages were:

```
Upgrade: brave-browser:amd64 (1.27.111, 1.28.106), libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.1), libegl-mesa0:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.1), update-notifier-common:amd64 (3.192.30.8, 3.192.30.9), libwbclient0:amd64 (2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.9, 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.10), grub-common:amd64 (2.04-1ubuntu26.12, 2.04-1ubuntu26.13), libglapi-mesa:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.1), libglapi-mesa:i386 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.1), libxatracker2:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.1), grub2-common:amd64 (2.04-1ubuntu26.12, 2.04-1ubuntu26.13), grub-pc:amd64 (2.04-1ubuntu26.12, 2.04-1ubuntu26.13), libgbm1:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.1), samba-libs:amd64 (2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.9, 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.10), grub-pc-bin:amd64 (2.04-1ubuntu26.12, 2.04-1ubuntu26.13), firefox-locale-en:amd64 (91.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 91.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libgles2-mesa-dev:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.1), distro-info-data:amd64 (0.43ubuntu1.5, 0.43ubuntu1.6), libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.1), libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.1), libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.1), libsmbclient:amd64 (2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.9, 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.10), shim-signed:amd64 (1.40.6+15.4-0ubuntu7, 1.40.7+15.4-0ubuntu9), libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.1), firefox:amd64 (91.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 91.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.1), mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.1), mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.1), update-notifier:amd64 (3.192.30.8, 3.192.30.9), mesa-va-drivers:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.1), libglx-mesa0:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.1), libglx-mesa0:i386 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.1)
End-Date: 2021-08-20  06:44:43
```

How do I get the Dock to reappear?

**Update**

@vanadium I can't enable Ubuntu Docks from `Extension` or `Tweaks`. See below. Can't do your step 4.

[image: ubuntudock error]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. First, install the Extensions tool (`gnome-shell-extension-prefs`), load it up and disable the "Ubuntu Dock" extension if it is not already disabled.
2. Reset the configuration settings of Ubuntu Dock to the factory defaults with the following terminal command: `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/`
3. (Likely not needed, but to make sure: log out then back in)
4. Reenable Ubuntu Dock in the "Extensions" tool. If you do not see Ubuntu Dock in the tool, try restarting first.

This will reset your personal dock configurations. An issue with the current configuration is most likely causing the problems. Ubuntu Dock is derived from the Dash to Dock extension, and shares the same configuration settings.

If problems persist, then there may be an issue at the system level. Then attempt a reinstall of the dock:

1. Remove with the command `sudo apt purge gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`. This will likely also remove the ubuntu-desktop metapackage. Likely not needed, but you could reboot now to be sure.
2. Reinstall `ubuntu-desktop`: `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`. This will pull Ubuntu Dock back in
3. If the event ubuntu-dock does not appear in the desktop environment, restart the system.

Comment: Thanks. But I can't do step 4. Appended this issue in my question. BTW, I thought Dash-to-Dock isn't compatible with Ubuntu 20.04 since its developer had stop work on it some time ago? Does this affect Ubuntu Dock?

Comment: Then there is also a system wide problem. Remove with the command `sudo apt purge gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`. This will likely also remove the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage. To be sure, reboot. Then reinstall `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`, which should pull ubuntu dock back in. Then try again to enable the extension. Report back, if this works I will add to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. :) After the last command, I noticed the extension `Ubuntu dock` did not appear in gnome-tweaks hence could not enable it. After restarting the system and login, `Ubuntu dock` appeared in the desktop environment automatically. No other setup step needed. Probably u can add the restarting system to your updated answer too. I wonder if using `Alt`+`F2` followed by `r`+`Return` to restart gnome-shell would have done the trick (in place of restarting Ubuntu)?

Comment: OK, I  added that a restart may be required. Please "accept" the answer: click the checkmark next to the question.

Comment: Pls remember to also include your instructions in your comments (followed by restart) to the answer as those fixed my issue. Your earlier answer did not fix my issue. ;) Cheers

Comment: I indeed added the system wide reinstall also. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Non-tech  newbie here: I removed gnome-shell-extensions and the problem went away.